# why are my LED lights not turning on?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, light

My led lights have worked fine for awhile, but today they wouldn't turn on! When I plug them in they flicker once and shut back off. I tried a different outlet and it did the same thing.

Comment: by the way the LED lights are light strips.

Comment: Is the driver putting out nominal voltage still?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include some more details, like make/model of the light strips, is the breaker tripping when you plug them in, what other loads are currently on this circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the driver has failed. If a quality product, there might be a warranty. If a cheap junky product, you probably can't even find the company, at least operating under the name you bought them from. That's part of the business plan that makes such things cheap, in every sense of that word.

In either case, you'll need new lights or at least new compatible drivers for the lights if you need working lights.

Comment: Well if it's quality, the proof of the pudding is in the refund/replacement.